# CSS Caching Issue in Chrome

Tags: html, css, caching

On my site, I have a template page which is styled using multiple stylesheets,  one of which (the stylesheet in question) is called style.css. On one page (page1) that is using the stylesheet I can see this stylesheet is applied. On a separate page (page2) using the same template, it is not being applied. However, I can see it being applied if I copy page2 and paste it into the same location under a different name (page3). Just to be clear page3 is using the same HTML as page2 and in the same location but I cannot see the style.css being applied to page2. This leads me to believe that there is some caching going on?

Something else that lead me to believe it to be a caching issue is that I could see the styling being applied to page2 in a different browser.

Am I correct is there caching happening causing this issue? If so how can I clear it to see the styling on page2? If not what else could the issue be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a caching issue, it seems to be a problem with the charset that is being used. Check to see if you are using the right charset for your application.

Comment: Good shout, for some reason one page was loading as UTF-16LE and one was loading with charset UTF-8!